# How to rename duplicate word as dup,dup(1),dup(2)

Tags: bash, duplicates

I have a string like `lisp,pascal,lisp,bash,bash,bash,lisp`
I want the result as `lisp, pascal,lisp(1), bash,bash(1),bash(2),lisp(2)`
**My approace -**

```
# converting string to array
string="lisp,pascal,lisp,bash,bash,bash,lisp"
set -f
array=(${string//,/ })
for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "$i=>${array[i]}"
done
```

I don't know much bash so I need a help...

Comment: Take a pen and a sheet of paper and try to solve it on paper. Write the algorithm [in points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) in your native language. First you have to come up with the algorithm to solve it and understand it, _then_ you can code it in a programming language. How would you do it?

Comment: I have already solved this in `PHP` language but bash syntax is too old and i am currently learning by doing this bash language

Comment: How did you solve it then? Could you post it?

Comment: If some how I get the frequency of the particular element of the array in bash then It will be easy for me (Do you know how to find the frequency of the particular array element  in bash ?)

Comment: I have updated my question as EDIT 1

Comment: Please do not edit solutions into questions. Make an answer instead.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have solved in PHP language but I am trying to solve it in `bash` and I am not able to solve in bash. That's why I didn't post it as an answer

Comment: `Do you know how to find the frequency of the particular array element in bash ?`, well, that would be a histogram - just create an associative array and increment count, along `declare -A histogram; for i in "${array[@]}"; do ((histogram[$i]++)); done`. dunno how it's related.

Comment: Thanks it is done

Comment: I see. It makes sense in the question then. Sorry. If you edit it in there again I will leave it. But allow me to recommend to phrase without words like "solution" or "EDIT". Just describe, for clarity, that you know how to do it in PHP (like this ....) but stress again that you want it in the other technology, just to avoid misunderstanding by other quick-shots like me ... Also, please take my apology. I was a little quick there.

Comment: @Yunnosch You were little quick because my rank in stackOverflow is just `1 1` hahahaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

```
string="lisp,pascal,lisp,bash,bash,bash,lisp"
array=(${string//,/ })
output=()
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    # if the element already exists in the array
    if ! printf "%s\n" "${output[@]}" | grep -Fxq "$i"; then
        output+=("$i")
    else
        # extract the last number of that element
        if
            last_num=$(
                printf "%s\n" "${output[@]}" |
                sed '/'"$i"'(\([0-9]\{1,\}\))$/!d; s//\1/'
            ) && [[ -n "$last_num" ]]
        then
            # increment it and output
            output+=("$i($((last_num+1)))")
        else
            # start with (1)
            output+=("$i(1)")
        fi
    fi
done
declare -p output
```

would output:

```
declare -a output=([0]="lisp" [1]="pascal" [2]="lisp(1)" [3]="bash" [4]="bash(1)" [5]="bash(2)" [6]="lisp(2)")
```

Comment: I want output as `lisp, pascal,lisp(1), bash,bash(1),bash(2),lisp(2)` this string

Comment: Okay thanks I have convert it in string , thanks again

Comment: In bahs, everythings a string. You want to join array elements with comma, typically `printf "%s\n" "${output[@]}" | paste -sd,`